# how to integrate stripe sca 3d secure django oscar

Tags: stripe-payments, django-oscar

I have seen this same question asked before but I believe the feature in stripe is still relatively new and not much information on Google, I'm a newbie at this but it keeps me up at night, can someone please share ideas of how to implement stripe payment intent in django Oscar and then confirming the payment on the client side? Right now I followed the Google group that discusses how to do it using charges api, I have converted the instructions for creating a Paynent intent but cards requiring authentication each time is failing, I am also not 100 %/ sure how to implement subscriptions when django Oscar checkout process is a 2 step process

Any feedback is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/dj-stripe/dj-stripe
try thisproject It is strip integrating with django-oscar

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32387816)